# correlate lists in python 3.5, how do I do?

Tags: python, python-3.5

quick question since I'm kinda new to Python 3.5 (it's my first programming language, actually) and I cannot fathom how to make it efficiently.

I want to create a little program in which I have a satisfaction query calculated from the results of several questions. Each answer corresponds to a int value that increases or decreases the satisfaction.

In the end, the program calculate an int satisfaction value for which I want to return a str text.

What I did - and I really think this could be optimized - is that for every value I have something like this:

```
if satisfaction == 0:
    print("not really satisfied")
elif satisfaction == 1:
    print("kinda satisfied")
```

... and so on.
I really feel like it could be better so I thought I could put the adjective into a list such as the following:

```
satisfaction_list = ["not at all", "not really", "kinda", "very"]
```

and make my way with it. Each satisfaction value would be returned as one of the degree from the satisfaction_list... Problem is: I don't know how to do it.

I though I could make two lists, one with the satisfaction values from -x to +x (let's call it int_satisfaction_value) and make it correlate with satisfaction_list (which we could rename str_satisfaction_value) in some way but I have no idea how to do it.

What I have come up with is the following:

```
if satisfaction_value == int_satisfaction_value[0]
    print(str_satisfaction_value[0])
```

but it doesn't solve my problem. Instead, it just replaces the string "print" input with a list one.

Sorry for the long post, I hope I was clear enough. if you have any further question I'd be glad to answer; thank you for your incoming answers!

edit: I'm ok with whatever you propose, whether it is lists or dictionaries, by the way

Comment: maybe you want a dictionary? like `{0: 'not at all', 0.5: 'kinda', 1: 'very'}`; or use the list indexes like `satisfaction_list[0]`?

Comment: Maybe! To be honest I thought I could use lists only considering that's what I'm learning right now. A dictionary sounds like a better idea, though.

I'll test that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary, for example:

```
satdict = dict(enumerate(["not satisfied", "satisfied", "very satisfied"]))
satisfaction_value = 1
print(satdict[satisfaction_value])
'satisfied'
```

Comment: I tried replicating your example in the interpreter but it raises a SyntaxError on 'print satdict[satisfaction_value]', saying it misses parentheses for calling a 'print'

Comment: @Asphalt_Ship: Daniels version is for python 2, you are using python 3. Just add the parentheses to print.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you want/insist on using lists, one way to improve your attempt is this:

```
for i in range(len(int_satisfaction_value)):
  if satisfaction_value == int_satisfaction_value[i]:
    print("I am " + str_satisfaction_value[i] + " satisfied")
    break # we have found a match, so we don't have to try all the other options.
```

An other way would be simply:

```
print("I am " + str_satisfaction_value[satisfaction_value] + " satisfied")
```

Note: This assumes that your `satisfaction_value` maps directly to the index of your `str_satisfaction_value` list. If that is not possible/desirable use a dictionary as suggested in the comments:

```
str_satisfaction_dict = {0: 'not at all', 0.5: 'kinda', 1: 'very'}
print("I am " + str_satisfaction_dict[satisfaction_value] + " satisfied")
```

Comment: Your first example raises a TypeError that states 'list' objects cannot be interpreted as integer, in my interpreter.. I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong..?

Comment: @Asphalt_Ship: ah, yes, my bad. I forgot the len() command. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to use a dictionary. 
You assign the values to variable as follows:
satisfaction_list = {1:"not at all", 2:"not really", 3:"kinda", 4:"very"}

To print "not at all" you use:
print (satisfaction_list[1])